# Controlling the formula representation in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I've created a formula like this:

```py
>>> a, b = symbols('a, B')
>>> i = Idx('i')
>>> bi = IndexedBase('b')[i]
>>> Sum(a*(bi/b), (i, 1, 5))
  5         
 ____       
 ╲    a⋅b[i]
  ╲   ──────
  ╱     B   
 ╱         
 ‾‾‾‾       
i = 1
```

While it's correct, it looks not like I want. I want to accent the fact that `b[i]/B` is a coefficient for `a` to make it easy to understand my thoughts when reading this formula. This is needed for documentation purposes within my Jupyter Notebook document. So I want to tell sympy somehow to represent the formula this way:

```
  5         
 ____       
 ╲      b[i]
  ╲   a⋅────
  ╱      B   
 ╱         
 ‾‾‾‾       
i = 1
```

After that I want to tell sympy to simplify the formula to make as little operations as possible. For example, this formula may be simplified this way:

```
     5         
    ____       
a   ╲      
─ ⋅  ╲   b[i]
B    ╱     
    ╱         
    ‾‾‾‾       
   i = 1
```

How do I achieve this with SymPy?

Comment: Which python/sympy version do you use?

Comment: Python 2.7.10, SymPy 1.0

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your exact code to work on my old system (Python 2.7.6, Sympy 0.7.4.1), so I had to modify it a bit while still trying to keep a very similar structure.

It looks like [`factor()`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/simplification.html#factor) could help you:

```
from sympy import *
a, b = symbols('a, B')
i, n = symbols('i n', integer=True)
bi = Function('b')(i)
f = summation(a/b*bi, (i,1,n))
init_printing()
```

`f`:

```
  n         
 ____       
 ╲          
  ╲   a⋅b(i)
   ╲  ──────
   ╱    B   
  ╱         
 ╱          
 ‾‾‾‾       
i = 1
```

`factor(f)`:

```
    n       
   ___      
   ╲        
    ╲   b(i)
a⋅  ╱       
   ╱        
   ‾‾‾      
  i = 1     
────────────
     B
```

Comment: `factor()` works for me when I define `i` as `i = symbols('i', integer=True)`. But when it's defined as `i = Idx('i')`, factor() moves both Indexed and Function outside of summation o_O. Looks like a bug. Is SymPy 0.7.4.1 more robust?

Comment: And the first part of question is still actual.

Comment: I don't know if 0.7.4 is more robust, I couldn't get your example to work. As for the first question, it's really just a pretty print difference, I don't know if you can do anything about it : the two expressions are exactly the same from a mathematical point of view. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I think you should not. I just want to dive deeper. The expressions are same from the mathematical point of view, but they are different from the point of human logic. I want to accent the fact that `b[i]/B` is a coefficient for `a` to make it easy to understand my thoughts when reading this formula. This is needed for documentation purposes within my Jupyter Notebook document. Also I've found that `separatevars()` works almost the same way as `factor()` - what is the difference?